# Add element to set in the form of list comprehension in Python

Tags: python, set, list-comprehension

I have a list of sets. I want to add an element to each of these sets, and I want to do this with list comprehension. This is what I have tried:

```
In [1]: sets1 = [set()]

In [2]: sets2 = [{1,2}, {1,2,3}]

In [3]: [e.add(0) for e in sets1]
Out[3]: [None]

In [4]: [e.add(0) for e in sets2]
Out[4]: [None, None]
```

My desired output is:

```
[{0}]
[{1,2,0}, {1,2,3,0}]
```

Why does the above code return `None` instead of an addition of elements to the list, and how I can make this work?

Comment: `set.add` works in place and does not return anything (thus your `None`s). If you want your desired output then run the list-comprehension but don't save its result. Check your `set1` and `set2` after the list-comprehension to get the desired output.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would suggest:

```
[e | {0} for e in sets1]
```

or:

```
[e.union({0}) for e in sets1]
```

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't use a list comprehension in this case, a plain `for` loop would be simpler:

```
for subset in sets1:
    subset.add(0)

print(sets1)
```

should give you the desired output.

I already pointed it out in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41083839/python-add-element-to-set-in-the-form-of-list-comprehension/41083882#comment69373374_41083839) why your approach seemingly did not work:

> `set.add` works in place and does not return anything (thus your `None`s). If you want your desired output then run the list-comprehension but don't save its result. Check your set1 and set2 after the list-comprehension to get the desired output.

So you could just check `sets1` and `sets2` after the list comprehension. It should return: `[{0}]` and `[{1,2,0}, {1,2,3,0}]` (order may vary because sets are unordered).

Answer (score 1):

Let's first regenerate your problem.

```
>>> test_set = set()
>>> test_set
set()
>>> print(test_set.add(0))
None
>>> test_set
{0}
>>>
```

As you can see, `test_set.add(0)` returns `None`. But this is an in place operation, so the item did get added., which is evident from the above snippet.

---

**How to solve the problem:**

You can `union` after making the element a set rather than using the `add` method.

```
>>> [i.union({0}) for i in sets2]
[{0, 1, 2}, {0, 1, 2, 3}]
```

If you have a list/set of element to add to the exiting list of sets, you can do the following:

```
elements_to_add = [3,4,5]
>>> [i.union(set(elements_to_add)) for i in sets2]
[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}]
```

However, this is not an in-place operation. `sets2` would be exactly same before and after running the above *list comprehension*.

Comment: It's very frustrating when people downvote without any logical reason.

Answer (score 1):

Actually your `sets1` and `sets2` variables have become the results that you want, because the `add` statement operates the `sets1` but not generate a new list.
You can `print(sets1)` and `print(sets2)` to testify.

Comment: Just a minor point: It does create a new list it just doesn't generate new sets. Apart from that I already mentioned that in the comment to the question and in my answer.